# Need docker registry URL for mcr.microsoft.com

Tags: docker, nexus, nexus3

In our org, we have to use Nexus as proxy for downloading docker images from internet as our servers won't have internet connectivity.

I've setup proxy for Docker hub registry using URL ""

I want to setup proxy for the new MCR (mcr.microsft.com) registry.

Can someone please tell me what registry URL should i configure in my proxy server to be able to pull images from mcr through proxy...

instead of below command, 
`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk`

I want to be able to use
`docker pull <IP_Of_Nexus_Proxy>:<Port_Of_Proxy>/dotnet/core/sdk`

Below is working for me and pull image from docker hub
`docker pull <IP_Of_Nexus_Proxy>:<Port_Of_Proxy>/hello-world`

Comment: Registry URL i configured for docker-hub is Http://registry-1.docker.io

Comment: https://mcr.microsoft.com is right, but you need to be running Nexus Repo 3.16:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19125

Comment: I'm using OSS 3.16.1-02 version of nexus

Comment: Are you having issues with that URL?